# Publish project files from Jenkins using Artifactory plugin "Include Patterns"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

In Jenkins (2.7), I've got a simple Maven 3 Java project. It builds and publishes the standard project JAR to Artifactory using Jenkins Artifactory plugin; no issues.

**Goal**

Now, I need to publish to Artifactory an arbitrary file, `deploycfg.yml`, alongside the JAR; not in it. So from a repository perspective, it should look like this:

```
com/acme/sbgroov/1.0.0.7/
-- sbgroov-1.0.0.7.jar
-- sbgroov-1.0.0.7.md5
-- sbgroov-1.0.0.7.sha
-- deploycfg.yml       <---publish this to Artifactory too!
```

**Tried**

I've modified the pom to move `deploycfg.yml` to `/target` upon building, then tried different configurations for `Include Patterns` in the Jenkins Artifactory plugin to pick up the files for publishing:

```
*.jar *.yml
**/*.jar **/*.yml
*.jar deploycfg.yml
```

The JAR gets published to Artifactory, but not `deploycfg.yml`. Tried putting the yml file in `/target/maven-archiver` instead of `/target`, but that didn't work either. Not sure what else to do at this point, perhaps the starting point for `Include Patterns` is not what I think it is, `/target`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using a Pipeline Groovy script.

```
println "Uploading artifacts to Artifactory.  Upload target is: ${uploadTarget}"

def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory'
def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.jar",
            "target": "${uploadTarget}/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.jar"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.war",
            "target": "${uploadTarget}/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.war"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "manifest.yml",
            "target": "${uploadTarget}/manifest.yml"
        }
    ]
}"""

def buildInfo = server.upload(uploadSpec)

// Publish build information.
buildInfo.env.capture = true
server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
```

However, I ran into the same issue you're having using the traditional Artifactory plugin UI in Jenkins.  I'm curious, did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: Try using **Deploy Artifacts to Maven Repository** post build action, instead of Artifactory plugin.

Comment: I am still clueless on how to achieve this ! Can you please let us know how you solve it.

Comment: I ended up using the pipeline script.